# How to put many string values in HasMap Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to put `String` values in `mapInstancesProducts`. But when I execute my code, only one value is added in my map. But if I code `System.out.println(ligne.substring(12, 20).trim(), ligne.substring(20, 36).trim())` that's display all my values

I have this code :

```
public static Map<String, String> getInstancesEnv1(Session session, String env1, String name1) {

//code

            for (int i = 4; i < result.length; i++) {

                String ligne = result[i].trim();

                ligne = ligne.replace("[37;41m", "").trim();
                ligne = ligne.replace("[0m", "").trim();
                ligne = ligne.replace("[30;43m", "").trim();

                if (ligne.contains("element(s) found")) {
                    break;
                }

                if (ligne.length() > 124) {

                    ligne = ligne.substring(28).trim();
                    ligne = ligne.replace("[" + name1, "").trim();
                    ligne = ligne.replace("ISTSHC044T:", "").trim();
                    ligne = ligne.replace("ISTSHC045I:", "").trim();

                    //System.out.println(ligne.substring(12, 20).trim() + " " + ligne.substring(20, 36).trim());

                    mapInstancesProducts.put(ligne.substring(12, 20).trim(), ligne.substring(20, 36).trim());
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return mapInstancesProducts;
    }
```

Comment: Where is `mapInstancesProducts` declared?

Comment: Can you show what `System.out.println(ligne.substring(12, 20).trim() + " " + ligne.substring(20, 36).trim());` prints? Perhaps all the keys are identical.

Comment: mapInstancesProducts is declared a the top the class

Comment: Maybe the length of the line is always lower than 124?

Comment: Maps associate each key with one value.  To have the effect of a map that associates keys with more than one value each, you can use a map whose values are collections.  For example,  a `HashMap<String, List<String>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add two values with the same Key in a Map. You did override the first value with the second.

Comment: Thank you, I've not seen this detail :-)

Answer (score 0):

The result of the System.out.println is : [image]

And with HashMap : [image]

Comment: Please edit your post instead of adding information in an answer.

Comment: Okay sorry for that